# WAL archiving from a standby backup strategy Postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to figure out if wal archiving from a standby is possible and a viable option for a backup strategy on Postgresql 9.3.

The idea is to be able to take regular base backups and wal archives from a standby server in a remote DR site.

Unfortunately, the archive_command functionality is not available while the server is in standby_mode mode so I am wandering if the wal archiving could be done successfully using alternative ways like rsync, lsyncd etc.

Has anyone tried to this path can you share your experience?

Comment: For base backups just use `pg_basebackup -X stream`. No WAL archiving required. You can use the WAL archives from the master its self for your DR, no need to take separate archives from the standby.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql provides a `pg_receivexlog` utility that can be used instead of `archive_command` to do wal log archiving.

[From the Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgreceivexlog.html):

> `pg_receivexlog` is used to stream transaction log from a running PostgreSQL cluster. The transaction log is streamed using the streaming replication protocol, and is written to a local directory of files. This directory can be used as the archive location for doing a restore using point-in-time recovery